# Patchwork style and color arrangement

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I have to do a patchwork and I need a particular colour and style arrangement. Right now  I have this:

[[image: Current image]

My code:

```
from graphics import *
colour = ["","",""]

def main():
    size= getSize()
    colour = getColour()
    win = GraphWin("Patchwork", size*100, size*100)
    drawPatches(win, size)

def getSize():
    while True:
        size = ""
        while not(size.isdecimal()):
            size = input("Please enter a valid size between 2 - 9 for your patchwork:")
            if not(size.isdecimal()):
                print("Only digits are allowed.")
        size = eval(size)
        if size < 2 or size > 9:
            print("The valid numbers are 2 - 9.")
        else:
            return size

def getColour():
    for i in range(3):
        chosenColour = validateColour(i + 1)
        colour[i] = chosenColour
    return colour

def validateColour(colourNumber):
        while True:
            colour1 = input("Please pick 3 colours {0}:".format(colourNumber))
            if (colour1 == "red" or colour1 == "blue" or colour1 == "green" or
            colour1 == "cyan" or colour1 == "magenta"):
                if repetitiveColour(colour1):
                    return colour1
                else:
                    print("Cannot enter the same colour more than once.")
            else:
                print("The possible colours are; red, blue, green, cyan and magenta.")

def repetitiveColour(colour1):
    return(colour1 != colour[0] and colour1 != colour[1] and colour1 != colour[2])

def selectingColour(row, size, column):
    return(column * size + row)%3

def drawLine(win, p1, p2, colour):
    line = Line(p1, p2)
    line.setOutline(colour)
    line.draw(win)

def drawRectangle(win, p1, p2, colour):
    square = Rectangle(p1, p2)
    square.setFill(colour)
    square.draw(win)

def drawPatchOne(win, position, colour):
    x = position.getX()
    y = position.getY()
    for i in range(5):
        drawLine(win, Point(x + 20*i, y),
        Point(x + 100, y + 100 - 20*i), colour)
        drawLine(win, Point(x, y + 20*i),
        Point(x + 100 - 20*i , y + 100), colour)
        drawLine(win, Point(x + 100 - 20*i, y),
        Point(x, y + 100 - 20*i), colour)
        drawLine(win, Point(x + 20*i, y + 100),
        Point(x + 100, y + 20*i), colour)

def drawPatchTwo(win, position, colour):
    x = position.getX()
    y = position.getY()
    drawRectangle(win, Point(x + 0, y + 0), Point(x + 100, y + 100), colour)
    for i in range(5):
        drawRectangle(win, Point(x + 5 + 20*i, y + 0),
         Point(x + 15 + 20*i, y + 90), "white")
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            drawRectangle(win, Point(x + j*20, y + 10 + i*20),
             Point(x + (j+1)*20, y + (i+1)*20), "white")

def drawPatches(win, size):
    for row in range(size):
        for column in range(size):
            if (row % 2 != 0 and column % 2 == 0 or
            row % 2 != 0 and column % 2 == 0):
                drawPatchTwo(win, Point(row*100, column*100),
                colour[selectingColour(row, size, column)])
            else:
                drawPatchOne(win, Point(row*100, column*100),
                colour[selectingColour(row, size, column)])  

main()
```

But I need this overall arrangement of patch *syles* and *colors*:

[image: Desired output]

Where 'F' indicates the second patch style of my patchwork above, the *square* arrangement.

I kinda understand how to do the colours as I would use only blue and orange and use a new `if` statement for the red. The main thing I really struggle with is the style of my final patch (*diagonal* or *square* arrangement).

Comment: this really isn't the place for homework help. If you have a specific technical issue ask it, but I don't think it's the right place to ask for a complete solution.

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) -- it's fine to ask about a specific technical problem you encountered while trying to do your homework, with a question narrowed to exclude content and specifications unrelated to that problem. It's not okay to just ask how to get a correct answer.

Comment: The thing is I really struggle with finding content for the Graphics library that can help me solve my tasks

Comment: The first two comments above cover everything I could say. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: The main struggle I have is doing the diagonal for my final patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that I think I understand what you're asking.  (I feel the communication problem is shared by both you and those who edited your question, leaving out necessary detail.)  I believe we can get the pattern you desire using simple tests on the `row` and `column` values in `drawPatches()` and simplifying color assignment.  I reworked your code to address this issue as well as a number of code style issues:

```
from graphics import *

VALID_COLOURS = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'cyan', 'orange']

colours = ['', '', '']

def main():
    size = getSize()
    selectColours()
    win = GraphWin("Patchwork", size*100, size*100)
    drawPatches(win, size)

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

def getSize():
    while True:
        size = ""

        while not size.isdecimal():
            size = input("Please enter a valid size between 2 - 9 for your patchwork: ")

            if not size.isdecimal():
                print("Only digits are allowed.")

        size = int(size)

        if 2 <= size <= 9:
            break

        print("The valid numbers are 2 - 9.")

    return size

def selectColours():
    for index in range(len(colours)):
        colours[index] = validateColour(index + 1)

def validateColour(colourNumber):
    colour = None

    while True:
        colour = input("Please pick 3 colours {0}: ".format(colourNumber))

        if colour in VALID_COLOURS:
            if not repetitiveColour(colour):
                break

            print("Cannot enter the same colour more than once.")
        else:
            print("The possible colours are:", ", ".join(VALID_COLOURS))

    return colour

def repetitiveColour(colour):
    return colour in colours

def drawLine(win, p1, p2, colour):
    line = Line(p1, p2)
    line.setOutline(colour)
    line.draw(win)

def drawRectangle(win, p1, p2, colour):
    square = Rectangle(p1, p2)
    square.setFill(colour)
    square.draw(win)

def drawPatchOne(win, position, colour):
    x = position.getX()
    y = position.getY()

    for i in range(5):
        drawLine(win, Point(x + i*20, y), Point(x + 100, y + 100 - i*20), colour)
        drawLine(win, Point(x, y + i*20), Point(x + 100 - i*20, y + 100), colour)
        drawLine(win, Point(x + 100 - i*20, y), Point(x, y + 100 - i*20), colour)
        drawLine(win, Point(x + i*20, y + 100), Point(x + 100, y + i*20), colour)

def drawPatchTwo(win, position, colour):
    x = position.getX()
    y = position.getY()

    drawRectangle(win, Point(x + 0, y + 0), Point(x + 100, y + 100), colour)

    for i in range(5):
        drawRectangle(win, Point(x + 5 + i*20, y + 0), Point(x + 15 + i*20, y + 90), 'white')

    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            drawRectangle(win, Point(x + j*20, y + 10 + i*20), Point(x + (j+1) * 20, y + (i+1) * 20), 'white')

def drawPatches(win, size):
    for row in range(size):
        for column in range(size):
            if 0 < row < size - 1 and 0 < column < size - 1:
                colour = colours[2]
            elif row % 2 != column % 2:
                colour = colours[1]
            else:
                colour = colours[0]

            if row == column:
                drawPatchTwo(win, Point(row*100, column*100), colour)
            else:
                drawPatchOne(win, Point(row*100, column*100), colour)

main()
```

**USAGE**

```
> python3 test.py
Please enter a valid size between 2 - 9 for your patchwork: 5
Please pick 3 colours 1: blue
Please pick 3 colours 2: orange
Please pick 3 colours 3: red
>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

If this is *not* what you want, rework your question to include an illustration of correct output.

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I needed!